# Split uint8 into 4 unit2 in C to have unit10 later

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I want to make an extension to my uint8 variable with 2 other bits to have let say uint10. For that I used this method, but it takes only the mask in the consideration.

```
void splitbits(unsigned int x){ //x=11001010 and i want to have this for any given X
   split[0]=(x>> 6) & 0x01 ; //split[0]=11
   split[1]=(x>> 4) & 0x01 ; //split[1]=00
   split[2]=(x>> 2) & 0x01 ; //split[2]=10
   split[3]=x & 0x01 ; //split[3]=10
}
```

Comment: If you want 2 bits in every element of `split` array, shouldn't you use `0x03` instead of `0x01`?

Comment: hello this can work only for this case where we know wich bits are,i look for for spliting unkonw data maybe without mask i'm not good with bitwise operation

Comment: yes it worked thank you ,i thought that i should use 0x01 or 0x02 for two bits but i was wrong .

Answer (score 1):

```
split[0]=(x>> 6) & 0x01 ; //split[0]=11
```

The comment is factually incorrect. You mask out all but the least significant bit, not the two least significant bits. You need to mask with binary 11 which is 3 in decimal or hex.

```
split[0]=(x>> 6) & 0x03 ; //split[0]=11
//                    ^ binary 11
```

However, if you are wanting to make a 10 bit number out of any other number, you can do it all in one go. i.e.

```
uint16_t my10Bit number = anotherNumber & 0x3ff // 3ff is 1111111111 in binary
```

I used `uint16_t` because that is the smallest portable type that will contain 10 bits.

Comment: he is correct,it's me who didn't  explain the problem,i only splits this number to add it to another number. i shift the split number by 8 and i use or operator to have a 10 bits number,so this is what i have to explain,i think it's correct for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

Some code for spliting buffer of bytes on couples of bits

```
unsigned char* splitcouplebits(unsigned char* buffer, int couplecount){ 
    unsigned char* v1 = (unsigned char*)malloc(couplecount);
    for (int i = 0; i < couplecount; i++) {
        int bn = i / 4;
        int offs = 3 + bn * 2 - i;
        offs *= 2;
        v1[i] = (buffer[bn] >> offs) & 0x03;
    }
    return v1;
}

//... main   
{
    unsigned char src[2];
    src[0] = 0xBB;
    src[1] = 0x13; 
    //1011101100010011      
    unsigned char* splits = splitcouplebits((unsigned char*)&src, 8);

    //first 5 couples of bits
    cout << (int)splits[0] << endl; //10
    cout << (int)splits[1] << endl; //11
    cout << (int)splits[2] << endl; //10
    cout << (int)splits[3] << endl; //11
    cout << (int)splits[4] << endl; //00
    //....

    delete splits;
}
```